# What is the equivalent of French Travaux Diriges (TD) in Anglo-Saxon Universities ? and who leads them?

Tags: mathematics, teaching, university, physics, lecturer

I made my predoctoral and doctoral studies in France. Even after a few postdoctoral years in Anglo-Saxon like Universities, I am still lost for some mapping between the French system and the non-French system, hence my question. (As a matter of fact, the French system may look from outside even more complicated if not obscure because the higher education splits between the Grandes Ecoles system and the University system. Whatever.)

In particular, I am wondering if a Lecturer in Math and/or Physics can lead TD like sessions in an Anglo-Saxon University ? I am looking for a position outside, not to say far away from, France.

Comment: There is no commonality in the structure of, say, British and American universities.  The answer may be totally different in different places.

Comment: I had not heard of Travaux Dirig\'es, but a look at https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travaux_dirig%C3%A9s makes me wonder if you are asking about something like the "Moore method" or related forms of "Inquiry Based Learning"? Or is this more like what, in the UK, we often call "workshops" or "tutorials"?

Comment: From my (admittedly, very limited) understanding of travaux diriges, I think the best term would be a seminar course here in the US, but ideally someone more familiar with the French system should answer.

Comment: @YemonChoi "Travaux dirigés" are just exercise sessions. The students have been to the magistral lectures beforehand, and in TD sessions they do exercises under supervision (students do the exercise on their own, can ask questions, and then either a student or the supervisor answers the exercise at the board).

Comment: @OP There is no such thing as "lecturer" in France (well there is something called "lecteur" but it's completely unrelated). Can you clarify your question? In my experience anyone with teaching duties can lead TD sessions, from PhD students to full professors.

Comment: TD, if I am not wrong, are the courses that are given in classrooms (and not amphitheater) which aim at applying and practicing the course. Students are given exercises there, and they review together with the course giver. They differ from "cours magistral" where the lesson takes place in an amphitheater (not a classroom), the lecturer being generally at least an assistant professor. The "cours magistral" is more formal, in some way.

Comment: @Blue_Elephant You are right, but I guess that you describe the French system. My concern is rather the Anglo-Saxon system. Otherwise, by Lecturer I meant the corresponding academic position as in Lecturer/Assistant Professor/Associate Professor/Professor/Emeritus Professor, not the person who effectively performs the lecture.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Merci. So this corresponds closely to the "workshop" format used in many places in the UK (or "lab session" in North American idiom)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion in comments and the Wikipedia article linked to above, TDs appear similar to a "recitation section" at some US universities. At my undergraduate university, the teaching assistant (TA) would get together with some subset of the students of the main lecture course who are assigned to that section and go over exercises assigned by the professor and cover or re-cover things from the lecture that were not very well understood by the students.

Comment: Naive question: is the TA a Lecturer ?

Comment: Not by title. TA is the title. Though sometimes the recitation section does involve the action of lecturing. They are almost always graduate students who are employed to assist professors with their teaching and grading.

Comment: So basically, you mean that Lecturers (the persons who hold this title) do not solve exercises or little problems with students.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle, sometimes, sometimes not. They may leave all of that to the TAs who run their recitation sections. I saw it happen both ways in classes I took. Lecturer, in the US, tends to be a lesser title over those who have the various Professor titles. While they both lecture, lecturers appear to me to typically be on shorter term contracts and have no clear path to tenure and no direct expectation to do research. Though, if they do good research during their own time, they may be able to be promoted to professors who are then expected to teach and do research.

Comment: What is the typical lecture time of a Lecturer in the US ?

Comment: @SphericalTriangle, no idea. Every university is different, and every department is different. The "typical" class, on the 2 semesters per year system, is 3 hours per week at 14 weeks. Teaching loads run from 1-1 to 3-3 or higher.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost in translation: for what does 1-1 stand ?

Comment: @SphericalTriangle, 1 class in the fall semester and 1 in the spring. Teaching loads for semester systems are often given in the number of 3-hour-per-week courses per semester of the academic year 1-1, 2-2, 3-2, 3-3, etc.